# What is the deprecated method andOperator() in jsonPath Criteria replaced with?

Tags: java, mongodb, jsonpath

I am updating some code, and I found a missing symbol on this deprecated method

> **public Criteria andOperator(Criteria... criteria)**
>
> Creates an 'and' criteria using the $and operator for all of the
> provided criteria
>
> Parameters:
> criteria -

I need to find a replacement, but I am unsure of what will provide the same functionality.  Thanks!

`Update`:
As mentioned in comments this is for `com.jayway.jsonpath.Criteria`

Here is the old code:

```
    public Criteria getCriteria(Criteria criteria, String attributeName, LocalDate date, String timeZone) {
        return criteria.andOperator(Criteria.where(attributeName).gte(date.toDateTimeAtStartOfDay(DateTimeZone.forID(timeZone))), Criteria.where(attributeName).lt(date.plusDays(1).toDateTimeAtStartOfDay(DateTimeZone.forID(timeZone))));
    }
```

I replaced it with this, but I haven't had the chance to build the project and test it:

```
public Criteria getCriteria(Criteria criteria, String attributeName, LocalDate date, String timeZone) {
    return criteria.and(attributeName)
            .gte(date.toDateTimeAtStartOfDay(DateTimeZone.forID(timeZone)))
            .and(attributeName)
            .lt(date.plusDays(1).toDateTimeAtStartOfDay(DateTimeZone.forID(timeZone)));
```

Comment: Are you sure it’s deprecated?  [The documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/query/Criteria.html#andOperator-org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Criteria...-) doesn’t seem to indicate that it is.

Comment: Interesting... the class I was looking at was:
`com.jayway.jsonpath.Criteria`
as opposed to 
`org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Criteria`.  The code I am working with is really old not written by me.  Maybe I should be using this other class?

Comment: It appears the jsonpath Criteria class had an andOperator method in version 0.9.1, but does not have andOperator as of 1.0.0.  Without seeing what your old code is trying to do, it’s difficult to suggest a replacement.